# ToList eating massive amount of CPU time

Tags: c#, linq, list, .net-core

**edit:** I tracked down the cause. Later on in the code I had made a mistake which caused non-colliding records to be merged into the main data store (t in the below code) for every record it didn't collide with, which is basically every record except for the one it does collide with, so after a few thousand compares, the master list would grow exponentially and would be several trillion records instead of a few hundred.

I am attempting to sort, search and merge a large amount of 3d datapoints that are in 300-400 sets. I've run into a issue with a single linq line which seems to be eating 90-95% of my processing time. under about 3,000 sets, the processing time is virtually non-existent, but the moment I hit 3,000 the entire process virtually stops.

dottrace is telling me that all of my processing time is dedicated calling and waiting on .tolist(), but I haven't been able to find a linq alternative that is more efficient. (I can always go back to the c++ implementation I had for this exact problem, but I was hoping linq might have a more efficient solution than what I can reasonably come up with.)

linq in question is

```
List<Point> collisions = t.Points.Intersect(streamline.Points, new PointsComparer()).ToList();
```

the intent of this query is to take all the points in t and all the points in streamline, compare them, and generate a list of all the duplicate points.

it may be worth noting that t.Points and streamline.Points have been presorted, so I could run a binary search on them, but I'm not sure how one would do that with linq.

would greatly appreciate if anyone can explain what I'm missing here that's causing it to attempt to generate so many lists.

for good measure, here are the point and PointsComparer Classes. (both  t.points and streamline.Points are list)

```
public class PointsComparer : IEqualityComparer<Point> {
    public bool Equals(Point x, Point y) {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x,y)) return true;
        return x.X.Equals(y.X) && Equals(x.Y, y.Y) && Equals(x.Z, y.Z);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Point obj) {
        int xhash = obj.X.GetHashCode();
        int yhash = obj.Y.GetHashCode();
        int zhash = obj.Z.GetHashCode();

        return xhash ^ yhash ^ zhash;

    }
}
public class Point {
    public float X;
    public float Y;
    public float Z;
    public float[] Scalars = {};
    public int OriginalIndex;
}
```

Comment: is `streamline.Points` or `t.Points` the same every loop iteration? there are some optimisations you could do by manually implementing [the logic `Intersect` does](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,5e205387a7b355ba), for example, making a `HashSet<Point>` of the list that does not change and reusing that hashset for all of the lookups

Comment: How are you using the collisions variable later in code? Depending on how its used, you can skip the ToList() call all together to save on a lot of allocations. Every time you call the Linq function Intersect(), it creates a pseudo-list to store the results in, and then calling ToList() will copy them into a NEW List<T> type. If you are not doing anything complex with collisions (only iterating for example) you can completely remove the call to ToList() while still being able to iterate on the pseudo-collection.

Comment: Why floats on the point class?, just curious, not sure the performance impact.

Comment: @BenAbraham I attempted to use .toarray instead but it only marginally increased performance. maybe there is something else happening in the query that's causing it get bogged down? the program does datasets 0-2,900 in about 2 seconds, and then as soon as it hits 3,000 it maybe does 1 data set a minute.

Comment: @Trey
required as part of the project.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I'll give that a look, something seems to be pointing me in the direction of thought that I've done something wrong with the intersect method and it's recursively looping or something.

IE: I can see that the filtering method 3 lines above that is called 30 times, but toarray is called almost 15 million times, that shouldn't be happening IMO.